# Statistics z score mean, sd and variance

Tags: statistics

i am confused about the z scores, the mean of z-scores is always 0 and the standard deviation and variance of z scores is always 1.
Why is this? And what is its significance?

reference:
[http://pages.ucsd.edu/~aronatas/zscore.html#:~:text=They%20give%20you%20the%20location,Z%2Dscores%20is%20always%201.&text=You%20add%20up%20all%20the,of%20scores%20you%20have%20added](http://pages.ucsd.edu/%7Earonatas/zscore.html#:%7E:text=They%20give%20you%20the%20location,Z%2Dscores%20is%20always%201.&text=You%20add%20up%20all%20the,of%20scores%20you%20have%20added).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with $X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$. This means that X is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$

If you transform you rv in the following way

$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$

you can mathematically prove that $Z$ is still a normal rv but with mean 0 and st dev=1.

That is the Z- score and it is very useful to calculate any probability of any Gaussian distributed rv.

---

Example:

You have a hole with diameter 100. The diameter is not perfecly 100 but is is a random number Gaussian distributed $X\sim N(100;5^2)$ say average 100 and sdev=5.
We want to calculate the probability that the diameter is $X\leq 105$

To do that we can standardize the distribution passing to the z-distribution, called Z-score, whose probability values are tabulated.

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X \leq105]=\mathbb{P}\left[Z\leq \frac{105-100}{5}\right]=\mathbb{P}[Z\leq 1]\approx 84.13\%$$

the result is read on the Gaussian table.

[image]

Comment: If i find the mean of the Z scores, it will cancel to 0?